# Infinite Tunnels in First Level?

Tags: eye-divine-cybermancy

In the first level, which is also a sort of tutorial, there is a grate that you can break open and crouch to walk inside of, right after you take the elevator up.

This tunnel takes you a few places and at one point it seems like a dead end and the only way to go is to drop a long way. You land in water and there is a ladder that takes you to these tunnels that just keep going, seemingly forever. they all look like this screenshot and when you get to the end of one there is a left or right bend and then it is another identical tunnel.

Are these tunnels infinite? Or do they lead somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, the first time I played this game that is what I did.  I went into that seemingly infinite tunnel and went all the way to the end.  Heading to the end of the very long one actually leads you to the end of the level/tutorial.  There will be a ladder to the water or bridge (can't remember which) and over the bridge is the end of the level where you will find a hackable door and through that a friendly NPC allows you to leave.  I hope this helps with this very deep and quite confusing game haha

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!! I haven't been on Arqade for a long time, so I just now saw your answer. That is so weird that it leads to the end of the level. It's really funny that we both found the same hidden, mysterious tunnels!